# Insert N elements in a div per row

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to insert elements () in my . I have N elements of 150px width and I'd like to insert as many as possible per row. The thing is that people have different sizes for their browsers and it is getting messed up.

Sometimes there is a big blank space on the right side. I'd like to reduce the div space to N*160 (150 of the image + 10 of padding) + 10 (left padding)

Below is an example of code followed by a fiddle I've created.

```
//HTML
<div class="gallerybox">
  <div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">

      <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
          <div class="myimage"></div>
      </figure>
      <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
          <div class="myimage"></div>
      </figure>
      <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
          <div class="myimage"></div>
      </figure>
      <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
          <div class="myimage"></div>
      </figure>
      <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
          <div class="myimage"></div>
      </figure>
      <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
          <div class="myimage"></div>
      </figure>
      <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
          <div class="myimage"></div>
      </figure>
      <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
          <div class="myimage"></div>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>


//CSS
.my-gallery {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.myimage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
}
.my-gallery figure {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.gallerybox {
   margin: 0 auto ;
   max-width: 100%; /* MODIFY HERE? */
   display: block;
}
```

I made this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zn50y3bf/1/) to ilustrate my problem. I believe I have to do something with the width using [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), but I couldn't put the pieces together.

Comment: When you say 'sometimes there is a big blank space on the right' do you mean, if there aren't many images you want them to become bigger than 150px wide and take up a % of the screen width? Also where is gallerybox in the HTML?

Comment: If there aren't many images I want to reduce the width of gallerybox or my-gallery. Sorry I forgot to add the gallerybox class in the html. It is a wrapper. I'm adding now

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of unnecessary styles.
e.g `.my-gallery` and `.myimage` you have `width: 100%` It's a div, it's 100% by default

`.gallerybox max-width: 100%; display:block;` are both unnecessary. (display block is default of div)

So because you want to change the width of the container based on number of images, you'll need to use either
server-side logic, javascript logic or an special CSS selector (might not be suppported)

Made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6c3yrqcu/3/) here. If number of images < 4 it sets width of .gallerybox to 50%.
Other it spans full width.